# Java for each loops reading from arraylist calling method

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

[This is each array list and reading in and making changes to be stored in each list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veZZX.png)I am trying to read from separate arraylists to iterate through them and use each iteration as a parameter in a method call at the end. However, it does the call with each iteration at the first level (field) then does the second (setter) and so on and so forth. I need to find a way to have them iterate and get the correct index of each param for the method for the size of the arraysLists.

Currently, if each list has 3 items in it, the first for loop will run through all 3 items in the method call, before moving onto the second loop. So, I will have the first list iterating, while the other 3 don't. Then, the first will stay the same, and the 2nd parameter (list) will iterate.[Sample Output Currently, red underlines are where other changes SHOULD be happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVTdi.png)

I would like to have each item in each array be called together, all at index 0 at once, then all at index 1, and so on. That would give me an ideal output for this, which is reading a list of fields from a text file, and generating Unit Tests to save time.

```
    for (int counter = 0; counter < fields.size(); counter++) {
  String field = fields.get(counter);

    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < setters.size(); iterator++) {
      String setter = setters.get(iterator);

        for (int tickah = 0; tickah < methodName.size(); tickah++) {
          String updatedMethodName = methodName.get(tickah);

            for (int wicked = 0; wicked < fields.size(); wicked++) {
              String updatedFieldNames = updatedFieldName.get(wicked);
              creatingMethod(updatedMethodName, updatedFieldNames, field, setter);

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify again for us, what behavior you're desiring and what you're actually seeing? Maybe it's clear to others, but I'm afraid that it's not very clear to me

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm with you :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. So I have that method call at the end with those parameters, and I would like to read each item from the respective arrayList to use as parameters in the method call. So index 0 from each on the first call, index 1 on the second, and so on. Does that help?

Comment: @CaptainChief - can you please update your question and provide some sample lists and some sample output (expected vs current)?  We'd like to help but it is very hard to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Again, it's still unclear. You've got nested for loops, and so the code inside all the nests should loop through all indices of all the lists, getting you all possible combinations. Again, how isn't this working for you?

Comment: Answer below, thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you have a solution, but in the future, perhaps make it easier for us to understand your question and answer you. You do see that he had to guess and provide *two* solutions because your question remains unclear.

Comment: Yup, i'll do better, I'll think a little more on my approach before I post. Sorry, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong here... but based on this comment from you:

> Yeah, I'm sorry. So I have that method call at the end with those
>   parameters, and I would like to read each item from the respective
>   arrayList to use as parameters in the method call. So index 0 from
>   each on the first call, index 1 on the second, and so on. Does that
>   help?

It sounds like you either wanted to use a single loop and re-use the counter on each array list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
    String field = fields.get(i);
    String setter = setters.get(i);
    String updatedMethodName = methodName.get(i);
    String updatedFieldNames = updatedFieldName.get(i);
    creatingMethod(updatedMethodName, updatedFieldNames, field, setter);
}
```

Or, potentially it sounds like you may have wanted to do more of a cartesian product where you loop through each individual list fully... in which case you should have use each list's size rather than fields.size() every time.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < fields.size(); counter++) {
    String field = fields.get(counter);
    for (int iterator = 0; iterator < setters.size(); iterator++) {
        String setter = setters.get(iterator);
        for (int tickah = 0; tickah < methodName.size(); tickah++) {
            String updatedMethodName = methodName.get(tickah);
            for (int wicked = 0; wicked < updatedFieldName.size(); wicked++) {
                String updatedFieldNames = updatedFieldName.get(wicked);
                creatingMethod(updatedMethodName, updatedFieldNames, field, setter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, your top solution worked. I should have used the single loop instead. I'm a little newer, so I thought I had to iterate through them all with seperate counters/etc. Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: Just for the record: four levels of nesting loops. That results in O(n^4), and in very *unclean* code. Shudder ....

Comment: Oh absolutely, I knew that, this was an MVP type approach i was trying to come up with quick to keep me from writing out 1000s of more unit tests

Comment: No problem.  +1 for cleaning up your question.  SO is great, but always try to make your question as simple as possible to help everyone out :).  Adding some sample input data/etc and clear expected output is always super helpful.

Comment: Alright, makes sense to me, noted! :)